# Related to x & y coordinate of the window

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

Where does x and y value i.e window coordinate is stored?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in LPARAM of the WndProc CALLBACK function for your window.

Suppose your LPARAM is lParam then

x = LOWORD(lParam) & y = HIWORD(lParam)

Comment: x value will get by LOWORD of lParam and y value will get by HIWORD of lParam.